# Getting ConstantExpression.Value when actual value wrapped into DisplayClass because of closure

Tags: c#, dynamic, closures, linq-expressions, expressionvisitor

Below is a simple demonstration code of my problem.

```
[TestClass]
public class ExpressionTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestParam()
    {
        Search<Student>(s => s.Id == 1L);

        GetStudent(1L);
    }

    private void GetStudent(long id)
    {
        Search<Student>(s => s.Id == id);
    }

    private void Search<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {
        var visitor = new MyExpressionVisitor();
        visitor.Visit(filter);
    }
}

public class MyExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1L, node.Value);
        return base.VisitConstant(node);
    }
}
```

`TestParam` method causes `VisitConstant` to be invoked on two different paths:

**1.** `TestParam` -> `Search` -> `VisitConstant`

In this execution path constant expression (1L) passed to `Search` method is a real constant value. Here, everything is OK, assert succeeds as expected. When `VisitConstant` is invoked via first path `node.Value.GetType()` is `Int64` and its `.Value` is `1L`.

**2.** `TestParam` -> `GetStudent` -> `Search` -> `VisitConstant`

In this execution path constant expression (id: 1L), is taken by `GetStudent` as an argument and passed to `Search` method inside a closure.

**Problem**

The problem is on the second execution path. When `VisitConstant` is invoked via second path `node.Value.GetType()` is `MyProject.Tests.ExpressionTests+<>c__DisplayClass0` and  this class has a public field named `id` (same as `GetStudent` method's argument) which has the value of `1L`.

**Question**

How can I get `id` value in second path? I know about closures, what a `DisplayClass` is and why it is created at compile time etc. I am only interested in getting its field value.
One thing I can think of is, via reflection. With something like below but it does not seem neat.

```
node.Value.GetType().GetFields()[0].GetValue(node.Value);
```

**Bonus Problem**

While playing with the code for gettting `id` value I changed `VisitConstant` method like below (which will not solve my problem though) and get an exception saying *"'object' does not contain a definition for 'id'"*

[image]

**Bonus Question**

As dynamics are resolved at runtime and `DisplayClass` is created at compile time, why cannot we access its fields with `dynamic`? While below code works, I expected that code would work too.

```
var st = new {Id = 1L};
object o = st;
dynamic dy = o;
Assert.AreEqual(1L, dy.Id);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is an article that explains how to do it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/08/01/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-iii.aspx), and includes code that does it. Basically, what you can do is to create an expression that represents just that subexpression, compile it to a delegate and then execute that delegate. (The article also explains how to identify subexpressions that can be evaluated, but I guess you're not interested in that.)

Using the code from the article, modifying your code to the following will work:

```
private void Search<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
{
    new MyExpressionVisitor().Visit(Evaluator.PartialEval(filter));
}
```

> As dynamics are resolved at runtime and `DisplayClass` is created at compile time, why cannot we access its fields with `dynamic`?

Because that `DisplayClass` is a `private` class nested inside `ExpressionTests`, so code inside `MyExpressionVisitor` can't access its members.

If you make `MyExpressionVisitor` a nested class inside `ExpressionTests`, `dynamic` will start working on the `DisplayClass`.

Anonymous types don't behave this way, because they are not emitted as nested `private` types.

Answer (score 5):

`VisitConstant` will not help here, as it receives a compiler constructed `ConstantExpression` that uses object of private anonymous class to store values lambda was closed over (The `DisplayClassxxx`)

Instead, we should override `VisitMember` method and inspect its `MemberExpression` that already has `ConstantExpression` as an inner `Expression`.

Here is working test with little reflection.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest2
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        Search<Student>(s => s.Id == 1L);
        GetStudent(1L);
    }
    private void GetStudent(long id)
    {
        Search<Student>(s => s.Id == id);
    }
    private void Search<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {
        var visitor = new MyExpressionVisitor2();
        visitor.Visit(filter.Body);
    }
}

//ExpressionVisitor
public class MyExpressionVisitor2 : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        switch (node.Expression.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.Constant:
            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
            {
                var cleanNode = GetMemberConstant(node);

                //Test
                Assert.AreEqual(1L, cleanNode.Value);

                return cleanNode;
            }
            default:
            {
                return base.VisitMember(node);
            }
        }
    }


    private static ConstantExpression GetMemberConstant(MemberExpression node)
    {
        object value;

        if (node.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
        {
            value = GetFieldValue(node);
        }
        else if (node.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
        {
            value = GetPropertyValue(node);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        return Expression.Constant(value, node.Type);
    }
    private static object GetFieldValue(MemberExpression node)
    {
        var fieldInfo = (FieldInfo)node.Member;

        var instance = (node.Expression == null) ? null : TryEvaluate(node.Expression).Value;

        return fieldInfo.GetValue(instance);
    }

    private static object GetPropertyValue(MemberExpression node)
    {
        var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)node.Member;

        var instance = (node.Expression == null) ? null : TryEvaluate(node.Expression).Value;

        return propertyInfo.GetValue(instance, null);
    }

    private static ConstantExpression TryEvaluate(Expression expression)
    {

        if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
        {
            return (ConstantExpression)expression;
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException();

    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! This is the fastest way to get the underlying values of a closure, this should be the accepted answer.