# How to deconstruct expression tree to get value of captured variable

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

Consider the following block of code:

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> pred;
{
    string s = "test";
    pred = x => x == s;
}
// how to retrieve the value of s from just pred?
```

The only variable in scope after this block is `pred`. How can we retrieve the value of the captured variable `s`, just using `pred`? I can see the value in the debugger by expanding the object graph of `pred`, but how do I do that in code?

Comment: `pred.Body.Right.Expression.Value.s`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `Right` won't be available.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You need to do some intermediate casting to make that work

Comment: And even then you need to do some funkiness with the generated class to get `s`

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705339/getting-constantexpression-value-when-actual-value-wrapped-into-displayclass-bec) will give you an insight on how to drill into the value properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do quite a bit of casting to get to the underlying value of `ConstantExpression` since the compiler will tuck the value away.

The following gets the right node via `BinaryExpression`, checks if the right node is a `ConstantExpression`, and uses the `FieldInfo` of the right node to get the value:

```
var rightNodeMemberExpression = ((pred.Body as BinaryExpression).Right) 
                                    as MemberExpression;
var fieldInfo = rightNodeMemberExpression.Member as FieldInfo;

if (rightNodeMemberExpression.Expression is ConstantExpression exp)
{
    var val = exp.Value;
    var retrievedValue = fieldInfo.GetValue(val);

    Console.WriteLine(retrievedValue); // will output "test"
}
```